# Changing colour of part of SVG elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I would like to use d3.js [timeknots](https://graves.cl/timeknots/example/index.html) component, which is a svg visualization consisting of [line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line) and [circle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle) elements. I wonder how can I apply a stopwatch animation, which changes colour of svg visualization over time.

I think I could create a coloured copy of whole visualization, which overlaps original visualization and change clipping of coloured copy over time. I am not sure if this is the best approach or there are better ways how to do that.

[image]

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: @Weedoze here you can see the visualization https://jsfiddle.net/uw5x4a5e/, but I don't want to spend hours of coding and don't be sure if it is a good approach.

Comment: set the colour to a linear gradient and manipulate the stops.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks a lot, I think it is better solution. You can answer the question and I will mark it as resolved.

Comment: If you provide code I'll adapt it to answer the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson I already created `linearGradient` for `g` element as a container for whole visualization and it works very well.

Comment: You can post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`linearGradient` element works very well in this use case.

```html
<svg class="timeline" width="809" height="150">
   <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" y1="0px" y2="0px" x1="232" x2="233">
         <stop stop-color="#1689fb"></stop>
         <stop stop-color="rgb(126, 126, 126)"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
   </defs>
   <g stroke="url(#gradient)" class="wrapper-timeline">
      <g clip-path="url(#clipLine)" class="wrapper-lines">
         <line class="timeline-line" x1="11" x2="798" y1="75" y2="75" style="stroke-width: 2;"></line>
         <line class="timeline-line" x1="798" x2="798" y1="75" y2="75" style="stroke-width: 2;"></line>
      </g>
      <circle class="timeline-event" id="knot-0" r="6" cy="75" cx="11" style="stroke-width: 2; fill: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.01);"></circle>
      <circle class="timeline-event" id="knot-1" r="6" cy="75" cx="798" style="stroke-width: 2; fill: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.01);"></circle>
   </g>
   <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href=""></use>
   <text class="current-time" x="0" y="97" style="font-size: 70%;">00:20:03</text>
   <text class="duration" x="770.859375" y="97" style="font-size: 70%;">01:11:24</text>
</svg>
```